# Facing issue while writing curl equivalent java code through HTTP Client

Tags: java, http, url, curl, http-headers

I have a CURL command and that is working fine when i executed it. Below is the curl command . If i am trying to write the same curl command in java using HTTP client i am getting the HTTP 403. I am not able to understand why the same error I am not getting when i executed CURL but in code i am getting . Can someone please help me in fixing my code .

```
curl -v -X POST "http://iapi-va3.svcmot.com/v1/gui/user.json?appid=4KCPMNRRT4VJBY54V3888YUOLHLICK28" -d '{"providerType":"MOTOID","email":"1234@idmtest.com","password":""}'
```

Below is my Java Code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://iapi-va3.svcmot.com/v1/gui/user.json?appid=4KCPMNRRT4VJBY54V3888YUOLHLICK28");
        post.addHeader("User-Agent","curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2");
        post.addHeader("Host","iapi-va3.svcmot.com");
        post.addHeader("Accept","curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2");
        post.addHeader("Accept", "*/*");
        post.addHeader("Content-Length", "66");
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        Header[] headerArray=post.getAllHeaders();
        for(Header h:headerArray)
        {
            System.out.println(h.getName()+"---"+h.getValue());
        }

        try {

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("providerType", "MOTOID"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "1234@idmtest.com"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", ""));

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            System.out.println("\n"+response);
            //System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("\n"+line);
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can someone please have a look on header part specifically? First i executed the CURL command whatever the request header that i get I added in my java code .Is it fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a differnece, that you are sending a json to server from the curl, but in your program you send it as parameters.

Obviously You need to serialise the params as json in your app before sending.

Comment: U mean I need to add all the headers in nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("", ""));

Comment: I don't know which library You are using, you should know how to do that.

Comment: I am using Apache HTTP client library

Comment: You need to send your data in the 'json' format in the body, not as params directly. You could use some JSON library to do the serialization. You could also write the json by hand to test it.

Comment: Thanks . I was making that mistake